# How can two declarations correspond without having the same name in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I guess it's a simple question, at least I can't think in any example. [standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#scope-4):

> Two declarations correspond if they (re)introduce the same name, both
> declare constructors, or both declare destructors, unless...

So. If I understood correctly, if I have two classes A and B, two constructors A() and B(), they correspond? maybe I'm not considering the ***unless***. But what would be such a example in which declarations correspond without having the same name?

Comment: Is `A` and `B` the **same name**?

Comment: It's talking about things like `int main() { int foo(); int foo(); }` that has two declaration to the function `foo`, which correspond to the same function.

Comment: @Eljay. but the text gives me the option. two declarations correspond if they have same name OR, both declare destructors. Well `~A() `and `~B()` declare destructors. I guess its a English interpretation problem, if so, sorry for it.

Comment: @Roman: "*unless...*" Maybe you should read the stuff that follows it.

Comment: They seem to correspond

Comment: @NicolBolas what distinguishes them in the _unless_ part?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: There's a link right there. It's not hard to read.

Comment: @NicolBolas you do not have a concrete answer?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Comments are not for answers. My point is that the OP just needs to read the rest of the paragraph. They only "seem to correspond" if you don't bother reading the entire text.

Answer (score 2):

The stuff after "unless" is rather important. In particular, this:

> - each declares a function or function template, except when:
>
>   - both declare functions with the same non-object-parameter-type-list,18 equivalent ([temp.over.link]) trailing requires-clauses (if any, except as specified in [temp.friend]), and, if both are non-static members, they have corresponding object parameters, or...

Even "corresponding object parameters" has a [definition](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#scope-3) which is slightly above the above paragraph. It includes the text, "their object parameters have the same type."

Constructors and destructors cannot ahve explicit object parameter types. Therefore, their object parameter types are [implicit](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.dcl#dcl.fct-8) and [have "object parameter" types](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-4) formed from the type of the class they're a member of. So constructors/destructors of different classes have different object parameter types, so their object parameter types do not "correspond", and therefore, this is an exception to the "each declares a function", which means that they these declarations do not "correspond".

Comment: But constructors do not have implicit object parameters (https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#general-2.1)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: That's literally the opposite of what that says. The phrase "an implicit object member function that is not a constructor" *by definition* means that there are "implicit object member functions" which *are* constructors. If constructors were not "implicit object member functions", then that sentence wouldn't need to exist.

Comment: I do not get what do you want to say. The standard: «If a member function is an implicit object member function that is not a constructor… it is considered to have an extra first parameter, called the implicit object parameter». So, this does not apply to constructors. They do not have an implicit object parameter. And can't be distinguished by it.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Then the standard is contradicting itself because paragraph 4 clearly says "For implicit object member functions, the type of the implicit object parameter is". It provides no exception for constructors. The only non-contradictory way to read this is to say that constructors are implicit object member functions, and they do have implicit object parameter types, but overload resolution doesn't use those types. Those types *still exist* and therefore still denote that the two declarations don't correspond.

Comment: I think it is obvious that this apply to the case when there is an implicit object parameter

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: The literal text disagrees. You can decide that this is a defect in the wording of the standard, but the meaning of the literal text is clear: these declarations do not correspond because they have different object parameter types.

Comment: /2 tells **when** there is an implicit object parameter. /4 describes **how** does it look in implicit object member function case. The paragraph about **how** does not need to discuss **when** again.

Comment: _but the meaning of the literal text is clear: these declarations do not correspond_ It is clear that they do.

Comment: Can a constructor and a destructor access `this`? If so, then they have to have an *implicit object parameter*?  (Right?)

Comment: @NicolBolas, I guess I didnt make it clear, I didn' t know from the beginning if it was the case for the constructors/destructors. What I really wanted was an example of correspondent declarations with different names

Comment: @Roman: I don't think there is a case where they can have different names. They can declare the same name, or they can declare ctors/dtors (which simply don't have names).

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: "*/4 describes how does it look in implicit object member function case. The paragraph about how does not need to discuss when again.*" And yet it does not say that. It does not say "when an implicit object member function has an implicit object parameter, ...". Constructors are "implicit object member functions". Therefore, they have a type for an implicit object parameter, even if paragraph 2 does not allow that parameter to exist in the manufactured overload resolution sequence.

Comment: @Eljay static member functions cant access `this`? If so, then they do not have an _implicit object parameter_? (Right?) 

Comment: @LanguageLawyer • Correct.  Unlike constructors and destructors that I had mentioned.

Comment: @NicolBolas. Pretty good discussion, helped me a lot. Ok I do think that there isn't a way that they have different names. But what would be the case that they haven't equal names? Like it is said, when declare ctors/dctors. But how? I'm trying to get some practical example of this possiblity

Comment: The set of candidate functions can contain both member and non-member functions to be resolved against the same argument list. So that argument and parameter lists are comparable within this heterogeneous set, a member function is considered to have an extra first parameter, called the implicit object parameter, which represents the object for which the member function has been called. For the purposes of overload resolution, both static and non-static member functions have an implicit object parameter, *but constructors do not*.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.match.funcs#2

Comment: @SMeznaric if the standard says smth. like «an object of type `T`» without explicitly saying that `T` can't be `void`, the standard contradicts itself, and this proves there are objects of `void` type 